# Wordpress query_posts returns post from unspecified categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve post from a category using query_posts but it returns post from the unspecified category other parameters such as sort and showposts works fine.

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'categories' => 'Partners',
            'imageswidth' => '200px',
            'imagesheight' => '115px',
            'imageslink' => 'Web_Link',
            'partnerscount' => 'All',
            'columnscount' => 1,
            'imagescrop' => 'No',
            'imagesblackhovercolor' => 'No',
            'imagesopacity' => 100,
            'imagesgrayscale' => 'No',
            'imagescolorize' => '',
            'imagesnegative' => 'No',
            'imagessort' => 'Date ASC'
        ), $atts));

        //$args = "category_name=".categories;
        //$catIDs = get_cat_ID( $cat_name='Partners' );

        $args = "cat_name=".categories;
        $args .= strtolower($partnerscount) != "all" ? "&showposts=".$partnerscount : '';
        $args .= $imagessort == "Date_ASC" ? "&orderby=date&order=ASC" : '';
        $args .= $imagessort == "Date_DSC" ? "&orderby=date&order=DESC" : '';
        $args .= $imagessort == "Random" ? "&orderby=rand" : '';



        query_posts($args);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        {
$output = $output.get_the_title();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wordpress documents (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

In order to show posts from a certain category you can use the next parameters:

> cat (int) - use category id.
>
> category_name (string) - use category slug (NOT name).
>
> category__and (array) - use category id.
>
> category__in (array) - use category id.
>
> category__not_in (array) - use category id.

The right parameter is: `category_name` and not `cat_name`.
Replacing:

```
$args = "cat_name=".categories;
```

with:

```
$args = "category_name=".$categories;
```

While `Partners` is the `slug` of the category, should solve your problem.

**Edit 1:**

Please notice , you wrote `categories` without the $ sign.
PHP treats it as a defined and not as a variable.
Try this line:
    $args = "category_name=".$categories;

**Edit 2:**
If you can't fetch the slug of the category,
try getting the ID of it by its name.

```
    $catID = get_cat_ID( $categories );
    $args = "cat=".$catID;
```

Comment: when I try category_name it does not return anything at all

Comment: Apparently, `Partners` is not the slug of the category.

Comment: Edited my answer, try the Edit1 & Edit2 suggestions.

Comment: I was specifying category name instead of the slug, by changing to slug it solves the problem. thanks